# Libcloud: how to upload an image?

Tags: cloud, openstack, libcloud, openstack-glance

I've looked through libcloud docs about OpenStack (https://libcloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compute/drivers/openstack.html), but couldn't find any method to upload a new image. Is it possible to just upload a new image, or I can only create an image from a node?

What I'm trying to do is run this command using libcloud

```
glance image-create --name "cirros" --file cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img
--disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --visibility public --progress
```

Cirros is a generic image for OpenStack, but it could be Ubuntu, Fedora ...

Anyone knows how to achieve this using libcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at the moment this is not possible, according to this open issue I found on Jira:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIBCLOUD-523

It is quite old (21/Feb/14) so it doesn't seem it will be added to libcloud. Not sure if the development team decision is to leave admin features outside the scope of libcloud. Anyone have other comments about that?